# Looping through arrays efficiently

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
[1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [ticket_id] => 12
            [client_id] => 174
            [thread_name] => 
            [added_by] => 2
            [created_at] => 2015-07-28 23:24:07
            [updated_at] => 2015-07-28 23:24:07
            [notes] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 21
                            [user_id] => 2
                            [notes] => Not all those who wander are lost!
                            [notes_attachment] => 
                            [deleted_at] => 
                            [created_at] => 2015-07-28 23:34:31
                            [updated_at] => 2015-07-28 23:34:31
                            [thread_id] => 7
                            [users] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [user_id] => 1
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [user_id] => 2
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )
```

And I need to manipulate the **users** array in the **notes** array to something like this.

```
[users] => Array
(
[0] => 1
[1] => 2
)
```

So, basically, I need an array for ids in the users array.

I tried doing it, but it takes three loop to get into users.

How can I do that more efficiently ??

NOTE: This is just one of the structure from multiple arrays. Like, I have 4 threads and multiple notes in each of them.

Also, I need to manipulate the existing array and not just take the data from it.

My attempt:

```
$tmp = array();
        foreach($data as $value) {
            foreach($value['notes'] as $notes) {
                if(!empty($notes['users'])){
                    foreach($notes['users'] as $users) {
                        $tmp[] = $users['user_id'];
                        unset($notes['users']);
                        $notes['users'] = $tmp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: There isn't really any faster way to do this unless you format your data differently or you know the id of the notes array you want.

Comment: This is the array I get using Eloquent in Laravel. It serves the purpose, but there's this little tweak I need to do for users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) -

```
$new = array_column($a[notes][0]['users'], 'user_id');
var_dump($new);
```

**Output**

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
}
```

[DEMO](https://eval.in/407742)

**Update**

```
$new = array();
foreach($a as $value) {
    $new = array_merge($new, array_column($value[notes][0]['users'], 'user_id'));
}
var_dump($new);
```

Comment: From the question it sounds like he doesn't know the id of the users array, thus the need to loop through them

Comment: @Ethan22 If the array structure is this then no loop needed. You can check the demo.

Comment: I don't this will work. I mean there are some 100's of entries having users in it.

Comment: True, if it is like this. I just assumed from the            ` [notes] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array` that there was a possibility of a [1] etc.

Comment: Ah, good point @b0s3. He could loop through using $a[notes][$i]

Comment: The index of notes cannot be always 0. It can also be 100.

Comment: You just have to change the array accordingly or do an extra loop.

Comment: But, this doesn't change in the existing array. I need to manipulate the existing array. That is the users array should have $new. And not just take $new out of the array.

Comment: Then do it. You cant expect us to do the whole thing for you.

Comment: Even I got the array that you gave me using array_columns. And that didn't serve the purpose of asking the question. My main question was how do I manipulate in the existing array.